# OSX terminal - change back to bash

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, zsh

My terminal is using `zsh` (`.zshrc`)

I don't remember how that happened.

How can I go back to bash to use `.bash_profile` instead?

Comment: "how that happened" - you updated to Catalina, where it's the new default shell. I have no clue how to revert, I'll leave that for someone else.

Comment: Ok, so maybe I will leave it like that.
I thought that I changed it by installing some tools.

Comment: General preferences in Terminal.app has an option for the default system shell or one of your choice, you could specify BASH there if you are hating on ZSH. My only problem ended up being a couple of minor changes to my .bash_profile to make ZSH recognize the commands I wanted work. There are a number of moving from BASH to ZSH articles out there you might find helpful, just a google away...

Answer (score 1):

```sh
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

will change the default shell back to Bash.